# count number of non overlapping occurrences in a string

Tags: java, string

Hello i am trying to solve a problem where i count the number of non-overlapping occurrences of a string s2 in a string s1. Example `String s1 = "abab"` and `String s2 = "ab"` the number of occurrences is 2. Another  example `String s1 = "aaabbaa"` and `String s2 = "aa"` the number of occurrences is 2. Final example if `String s1 = "aabbaa"` and `String s2 = "AA"` the number of occurrences equal 0. 
How would i go about the problem?

Idea:
I know if i match the String s2 in s1. i move to the next position by adding the current index position with s2.length and if they are not equal increment the current index position by 1. My problem don't know how to start? How would you use iteration to solve this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So your question is how to iterate in Java?

Comment: @crush not to iterate but how to go abut this particular problem.

Comment: Try https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @crush i know i just cannot compare both strings as it will return false. Should i iterate character by character

Comment: It seemed to me like your idea would work. You will need an array of characters to iterate first. You get there with `char[] chars = s2.toCharArray();`. Then iterate until you run out of characters or the remaining characters is less than the length of your needle.

Comment: @crush ok if i both have convert them into char arrays. Then have a boolean flag will set to true if occurrences in s2 matches in s1 and set to true and if not set to false.

Comment: I don't think you need a boolean flag for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will be self-explanatory (using [String.indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-)):

```
public int countOccurrences(String haystack, String needle) {
  int count = 0, offset = 0, index;
  // As long as there is another occurrence...
  while((index = haystack.indexOf(needle, offset)) != -1) {
    // Skip already matched parts the next time
    offset = index + needle.length();
    // Increment counter
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

**Edit:** @JennFitz requested a recursive version, so here it is (although the above method is much better):

```
public int countOccurrences(String haystack, String needle) {
  int index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
  if(index == -1) return 0;
  int offset = index + needle.length();
  return 1 + countOccurrences(haystack.substring(offset), needle);
}
```

Comment: @JennFitz http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: @still_learning thanks so much i am analyzing the document and practicing it as we speak u have been of much help.